# How to join range of a splitline in Python

Tags: python

I have a log file in text format and now i want to convert it to Json.
I had done half of the code but i have some issues in joining the rest of the splitline.
So, i already split the first 4 row , but i want the start from "rotary" until the end of the string to be the fifth row.  How can i do that ?

**The log file:**
[image]

**My Code:**

```
with open('mazda', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for content in file:
        con = str(content)
        con = con.split(' ')

        '''
         0 = date
         1 = time and code (must split this)
         2 = EMPTYY
         '''
        #
        conDate= con[0]
        con2 = con[1:]
        #time
        tmp_str1 = con[1]
        tmp_str1 = tmp_str1[:8]

        conTime = tmp_str1
        #code
        tmp_str2 = con[1]
        tmp_str2 = tmp_str2[9:]

        conCode = tmp_str2
        conStatus = con[3]


        # 데이터 가공
        file_data["Date"] = conDate
        file_data["Time"] = conTime
        file_data["Code"] = conDate
        file_data["Status"] = conStatus

        # output to JSON

        tmp = json.dumps(file_data, ensure_ascii=False, indent="\t")
        print(tmp)
        result = ""
        result += (tmp + "," + "\t")

        # print(json.dumps(file_data, ensure_ascii=False, indent="\t"))
    print("result: ")
    print(result)
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve. Can you show the result you're getting, and the one you would like to get ?

Comment: what i get from my code: [link](https://ibb.co/DkFfqC7). I need it to be like this [link](https://ibb.co/q50PSx8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rejoin all the content since the third element of your line splitted by spaces.
I also recommend you to split the time and code with ";" instead of getting them by indexing.

```py
file_example=["DATE HOUR;LONG SYNC ROTATORY SOMETHING WORD", 
              "DATE HOUR;LONG SYNC ROTATORY SOMETHING WORD"]

for line in file_example:
    splitted_line = line.split(" ")
    
    file_data={}
    file_data["Date"] = splitted_line[0]
    
    time_and_code = splitted_line[1].split(";")
    file_data["Time"] = time_and_code[0]
    file_data["Code"] = time_and_code[1]
    
    
    file_data["Status"] = splitted_line[2]
    file_data["Fifth_row"] = " ".join(splitted_line[3:])
    
    print(file_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. yes i should split the time and code with ; instead of index hahah

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is a pattern to the log file you have. Your intended 4th and 5th column is seperated by a space. So what you can do is when you have the last string e.g
"SYNC Rotary.... Busysni"
You could split it based on space. The first string will always be your 4th column and the rest is your 5th which you can join with space.

Comment: i had already split the whole line with spacebar, but the fifth row should be all join together instead stop at just "rotary..". For example, if i split it with spacebar, it will become 'rotary', 'mov' .. What i want is 'Rotary mov'

Comment: Hey zhuang, it would be helpful to see what result your getting atm compared to what you need.

Comment: basically when you split based on ' ', you will always get the date in the 0th element, the time in the 1st element and your 'SYNC' in the 2nd element. the rest aka [3:] is your 5th column which you can join by:

fifth = " ".join(con[3:])

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you have different kind of blanks in your text.
Using split without any parameter will split the text based on any kind of blanks

```
splitted_line = line.split()
```

However, since your 5th column also have blanks you want to limit the split with the first three elements :

```
splitted_line = line.split(None,3)
```

Final result :

```
splitted_line = text.split(None,3)

file_data={}
file_data["Date"] = splitted_line[0]
file_data["Time"] = splitted_line[1].split(";")[0]
file_data["Code"] = splitted_line[1].split(";")[1]
file_data["Status"] = splitted_line[2]
file_data["Fifth_row"] = splitted_line[3]
```